# Django:Get access cookies in views which are set by javascript

Tags: javascript, django

I set some cookies through javaScript:

default.js

```
function checkCookie() {
    var location=getCookie("loc");
    var stat=getCookie("stat");
    if (location != "" && stat != "") {
        alert("Welcome again  to " + location +" and status is "+stat);
    } else {
       location = prompt("Please enter your address:","");
       status = prompt("Please enter the status:","");
       if (location != "" && location != null && status != "" && status !=null) {
           setCookie("loc", location, 30);
           setCookie("stat", status, 30);
       }
    }
}
```

views.py

```
if 'loc' in request.COOKIES['loc']
    return loc = request.COOKIES['loc']
els 'stat' in request.COOKIES['stat']
    return stat = request.COOKIES['stat']
```

I am confused in views.py if i can get access the variables or not?

Comment: You can, but not with that code, which is invalid syntax in Python; you can't operate on an assignment statement. Drop the `loc =` and `stat =`.

Comment: Do mean to say loc= , stat= in python script?If yes then how can i store the value of COOKIE in python code?